# Python 3.5 - PyInstaller not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

im coding a program in Python 3.5.1 and i intended to use PyInstaller to create an excutable, i've used PyInstaller before but now it doesn't seem to work, wich i find weird because it worked before.

I even tried with a simple hello world program but it doesnt work. PyInstaller creates a "warn...txt" file wich as a lot of warnings, saying that theres "No module named (module name) and then the path to the project directory". When i used it before it never gave those warnings and modules were imported sucessfully.

I know that this isnt a lot of information but even with the hello world program (without importing any module) it doesnt seem to work, it creates the executable but i when i run it nothing happens.

Do you have any idea what it might be? and what approach should i take in order to resolve this problem?

Here's some of the output in the command line

[image: Initializing pyinstaller]

[image: Here's when it says that the warn.txt file is created]

[image: Here's the end of the execution of pyinstaller]

[image: Here's some of the log created in the warns.txt file]

Comment: Can you show what the output from the command line prints when you try? Or provide some examples of entries from the "warn...txt" file?

Comment: yes i can, i will update the question

Comment: i've updated the question

Comment: Just to confirm... can you verify that you have visual studio installed... or at least some other compiler such as gcc? The instructions for pyinstaller on http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/ under the heading "Building for Windows" is what I am wondering may be the problem. Perhaps a dependency has changed since you used it last time.

Comment: i do have visual studio installed. i've recently installed the python tools plugin.